# How can I get git-extensions display a flat list of commits when filtering instead of a skewed one?

Tags: git, git-extensions

In git extension, when you filter to display all the commits in a branch, you get a nice flat list of all the commits of the branch:

[image]

But if you try to filter based on the words of the commits, you get this weird display:

[image]

This is particularly inconvenient if you have a large number of commits matching the filter, because you have a crazy indentation level near the end of the list.

So two questions in one:

1. Why does it look like that ? Why so much hatred ?
2. Is there a possibility to workaround that to get a flat list ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this representation is the fact that those commits are not directly related.
Showing those commits in a single column - like in the first screenshot - it would look like they are parents and children of each other.

As you can see for issues 36363 and 36277 it only displays them in one column, because 36363 was the immediate next commit of 36277.

As far as I know there is no way to change this.

Answer (score 5):

I understand Daniel Hilgarth's answer, but I still think it's a bad answer to the issue. Maybe they should do something like this for the commits that are in the same branch:

[image]

Comment: +1 : Agreed, that would look much nicer while still transporting the same information as the current representation.